# Can Task Scheduler check triggers with AND condition?

Tags: task-scheduler

For instance, I want to execute program only at startup AND at 10:00 PM.

As I know, Task Scheduler checks triggers with OR-condition.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Using AND would make the task run **only if** the machine was started up at exactly 10pm `if(startup AND 10pm){do stuff;}`. If you use OR, it will occur if **either** of those conditions are true. `if(startup OR 10pm){do stuff;}`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't think of that. Thank you for pointing that out! I should change the algorithm. Maybe run .bat file at startup, which will check current time (between 10pm and 10:10pm) and then run my program.